# Cauchy Schwarz Inequality for Schur product?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $M_{2^k}=M_2\otimes M_2\otimes\cdots \otimes M_2$ and $P_{2^k}=P_2\otimes P_2\otimes\cdots \otimes P_2$ where $M_2=\left[\begin{matrix}
1&1\\
1&0\\
\end{matrix}\right]$ and $P_2=\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}\\
\end{matrix}\right]$ and left $F=(-1)^{\circ M}$ where $\circ$ refers to element wise power operation.

Let $x,y\in \{0,1\}^{2^k}$.

Is $F_{2^k}\odot P_{2^k}= (F_2\odot P_2)\otimes(F_2\odot P_2)\otimes\cdots\otimes(F_2\odot P_2)$ where $\odot$ is the element wise (Schur) product?

Is $|x(F_{2^k}\odot P_{2^k})y'|^2\leq|xF_{2^k}F_{2^k}'y'||xP_{2^k}P_{2^k}'y'|\leq \frac{1}{{k}}$?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question, I can verify that the mixed product rule for the Kronecker product is
$$
(A*B)\otimes(X*Y) = (A\otimes X)*(B\otimes Y)
$$ 
where * can be the Schur, Frobenius, or Matrix product -- and assuming the matrices are of compatible sizes for each kind product.

Not sure about the inequality in your second question.